# Python selenium Cookies wont work with Twitter?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, cookies, twitter, automation

if you save selenium cookies for twitch for example, and you run a different instance and load the cookies, you are logged in. However, if you try the same with twitter, it's not working.
Does anyone know why or how to fix it?
I'm using python latest version

Comment: there are many approaches to detect you besides cookies. maybe twitch doesn't use them but twitter does.

Comment: any idea how im still able to login

Comment: have you tried to use proxies?

Comment: in a way when for each of your instances you use certain exact proxy